# Startup-Applications; difference between remove and uncheck

Tags: gnome, .desktop, startup-applications

What is the difference between removing a startup-application and un-checking it?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Gnome.[image]

In this example, what is the difference between leaving "Snap user application autostart helper" unchecked verses clicking "Remove"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If you remove it, its representation in `~/.config/autostart/` (.desktop file) is deleted.
- If you uncheck it, its line in the .desktop file:

  ```
  X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
  ```

  is changed into:

  ```
  X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
  ```

[image]

#### In your specific case:

The original of the .desktop file in your example resides in `/etc/xdg/autostart`, which is the "global" directory for autostart applications. These work for all users. 
If you uncheck one of these, a local copy is made, with the changes I described. 
The local, "unchecked" one will then overrule the one in `/etc/xdg/autostart`.

Comment: Thanks. And then to add it back, it looks like one needs to know the command to launch. Which isn't that hard to find, but can be a pain. It seems like there is no disadvantage to un-checking if you think you may EVER want it to be a start-up application again.

Comment: @Shai Right! no harm in just leaving it unchecked.